# What the decimal number in seconds bellow the cost percentage means in the SQL Server Graphical Execution Plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

The number is highlighted in the image below.

[image]

It would be nice to have a reference to some Microsoft Doc explaining it as well.

Answer (score 3):

It is a measure of elapsed time from an actual (contrasted with estimated) execution plan. In your specific example, it's saying that it took 0.062 seconds (i.e. 62 milliseconds). Interpreting that number depends on whether you're in batch mode or row mode. [This article](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/03/sql-performance/execution-plan-timings) is a good read. Two excerpts from it:

> In pure batch mode plans, you need to manually sum current and child operator times to obtain the cumulative elapsed time at any given node.

> The row mode operators will include a cumulative total up to that point in the plan, including all child operators.